# Not able to get IEnumerable collection of view model, current enumerator is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razorengine

```
public class CityDto : IEnumerable<CityDto>
{
    public IEnumerator<CityDto> AllCities { get; set; }

    private List<CityDto> _CityDto;

    public IEnumerator<CityDto> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _CityDto.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _CityDto.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the CityMasterdto class.
    /// </summary>
    public CityDto()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the CityMasterdto class.
    /// </summary>
    public CityDto(string city_name, long state_id, bool active)
    {
        this.City_name = city_name;
        this.State_id = state_id;
        this.Active = active;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the state name value.
    /// </summary>
    public string State_name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the City_id value.
    /// </summary>
    public long City_id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the City_name value.
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name="City Name")]
    [Required]
    public string City_name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the State_id value.
    /// </summary>
    public long State_id { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

And this is my controller code:

```
public ActionResult index()
{
     return View(GetCities(obj.Details()).AsEnumerable());
}

private IEnumerable<CityDto> GetCities(DataSet ds)
{
        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            yield return new CityDto
            {
                City_id = Convert.ToInt32(row["city_id"]),
                City_name = Convert.ToString(row["city_name"]),
                State_name = Convert.ToString(row["state_name"]),
                State_id = Convert.ToInt32(row["state_id"])
            };
        }
}
```

There's not any build errors but when I run the code, I get an error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MvcApplication.Areas.Admin.Controllers.CityController+d__1', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MvcApplication.Areas.Admin.Models.CityDto'.

[image: image for debug info for what is being returned]

but I do not understand what that means....

```
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<MvcApplication.Areas.Admin.Models.CityDto>.Current == null
```

and

```
System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current == null
```

also

```
ds == null
```

but results view shows the expected data

Comment: Your `_CityDto` is never initialized.

Comment: where should i initialize it?

Comment: I don't know. What do you want to do with it?

Comment: i wanted to return cities to a strongly type view ,it gave me error saying object should be IEnumerable type so i inherited : IEnumerable<CityDto> in view model then i used yeild return code to get ienumerable cites but it still giving me error and the same error i explained here

Comment: i initialized  it like private List<CityDto> _CityDto =new List<CityDto>(); but same error exists

Comment: again then the error is The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MvcApplication.Areas.Admin.Controllers.CityController+<GetCities>d__1', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MvcApplication.Areas.Admin.Models.CityDto'.

Answer (score 0):

i had to import ienumerable model in view too 
l`IEnumerable<MvcApplication.Areas.Admin.Models.CityDto>`

not like `<MvcApplication.Areas.Admin.Models.CityDto>`

and also i used this in controller index httpget acton

```
  var model = obj.Details().Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(t => new CityDto {City_id=t.Field<long>("city_id"),
        State_id=t.Field<long>("state_id"),
        State_name=t.Field<string>("state_name"),
        City_name=t.Field<string>("city_name")
        });
        //var model = GetCities(obj.Details()).AsEnumerable().Select(t => t);
        return View(model);
```